# Clean install of SQL Server Express 2005 and Vista x64 Home Preminum

Tags: sql-server-2005

The install for SQLSRVREXP 2005, for Vista x 64 its SQLEXPR_ADV.EXE downloaded from 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=b448b0d0-ee79-48f6-b50a-7c4f028c2e3d&displayLang=en

The first part of the installation is an analysis of the computer's configuration.

There was one warning.  Opening the details shows:

- ASP.Net Version Registration Requirement (Warning)
  Messages

  - ASP.Net Version Registration Requirement
  - Failed to find the ASP.Net Version Registration with Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS)

What does the "ASP.Net Version Registration with Microsoft IIS" mean and how would I fix this?

**Update:**
Since IIS is referenced in the report, I checked the status of IIS on my system and it's up and running. I also checked ASP.NET, likewise that's running as a service.

My guess is that it's some component of the IIS that it's looking for. In my XP/PRO machine I installed SQL Server Express 2005 without any warnings. It's running IIS 6.0 with ASP.NET services. I'm not sure if that advances the issue or not, but I thought I would include it for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's because you're installing the advanced services version which includes SQL Server Reporting Services.  As a web server based application it's checking that you've got IIS and ASP.NET installed.  If you're not going to install the SSRS option then I would say you can safely ignore it otherwise you're not going to be able to run SSRS without IIS and ASP.NET installed.